# (Postgres/Spring Boot/JPA) Deserialization error / Invalid Stream header: 5C78613

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot, deserialization

I have a simple web service which stores objects to a PostgresSQL database. I am encountering a  `invalid stream header: 5C786163` error. The hex decodes to the `\xac` or `¬` symbol but I cannot locate where this symbol is coming from at all!

Full Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.sps.service.RefreshLocalDbService.savePlaylist(RefreshLocalDbService.java:166) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sps.service.RefreshLocalDbService.saveSpotifyPlaylist(RefreshLocalDbService.java:116) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sps.service.RefreshLocalDbService.saveSimplePlaylistsToDatastore(RefreshLocalDbService.java:175) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sps.service.RefreshLocalDbService.pullLocationPlaylists(RefreshLocalDbService.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
at com.sps.service.RefreshLocalDbService.main(RefreshLocalDbService.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2790) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4019) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:438) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:522) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 5C786163
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:354) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

The relevant classes are below, full source available [here](https://github.com/AlastairMiller/Spotify-Polling-Service%20here):

**RefinedPlaylist.java**

```
public class RefinedPlaylist implements Serializable {
@Id
private String id;
private URI uri;
private URL externalURL;
private Integer numOfFollowers;
private String href;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> images;
private String name;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = RefinedUser.class)
private RefinedUser refinedUser;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = RefinedTrack.class)
private List<RefinedTrack> refinedTracks;
}
```

**RefinedUser.java**

```
public class RefinedUser implements Serializable {
@Id
private String id;
private URI uri;
private String displayName;
private URL externalUrl;
private Integer numOfFollowers;
private String href;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> images;
}
```

**RefinedTrack.java**

```
public class RefinedTrack implements Serializable {
@Id
private String id;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = RefinedArtist.class)
private List<RefinedArtist> refinedArtists;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = RefinedPlaylist.class)
private List<RefinedPlaylist> refinedPlaylists;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> availableMarkets;
private int discNum;
private int durationMs;
private boolean explicit;
private URL externalURL;
private String href;
private String name;
private URL previewURL;
private int trackNumber;
private int popularity;
private URI uri;
}
```

**RefinedArtist.java**

```
public class RefinedArtist implements Serializable {
@Id
private String id;
private URL externalURL;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> genres;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = RefinedArtist.class)
private List<RefinedArtist> refinedArtists;
private String href;
private String name;
private String type;
private int followers;
private int popularity;
private URI uri;
}
```

**MainService.java**

```
 private void savePlaylist(SpotifyApi api, RefinedPlaylist fullRefinedPlaylist) {

    if (playlistRepository.findById(fullRefinedPlaylist.getId()) != null) {
        playlistCleanup(api, fullRefinedPlaylist);
    }

    if (userRepository.findById(fullRefinedPlaylist.getRefinedUser().getId()) == null) {

        RefinedUser newRefinedUser = DownstreamMapper.mapUser(pullUser(api, fullRefinedPlaylist.getRefinedUser().getId()));
        userRepository.saveAndFlush(newRefinedUser);

    }
    ArrayList<String> songIdArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fullRefinedPlaylist.getRefinedTracks().size(); i++) {
        if (trackRepository.findById(fullRefinedPlaylist.getRefinedTracks().get(i).getId()) == null) {
            songIdArrayList.add(fullRefinedPlaylist.getRefinedTracks().get(i).getId());
        }
    }
    if (songIdArrayList.size() > 0) {
        List<Track> trackArrayList = pullSongs(api, songIdArrayList);
        if (trackArrayList != null) {
            ArrayList<String> artistIdArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Track track : trackArrayList) {
                if (track != null) {
                    for (int p = 0; p < track.getArtists().length; p++) {
                        if (artistRepository.findById(track.getArtists()[p].getId()) == null) {
                            artistIdArrayList.add(track.getArtists()[p].getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Artist> artistList = pullArtists(api, artistIdArrayList);
            if (artistList != null) {
                for (Artist artist : artistList) {
                    artistRepository.saveAndFlush(DownstreamMapper.mapArtist(artist));
                    log.info("Saved Artist: {} to the database", artist.getName());
                }
            }

            for (Track track : trackArrayList) {
                trackRepository.saveAndFlush(DownstreamMapper.mapSong(track));
                log.info("Saved Song: {} to the database", track.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    log.error(fullRefinedPlaylist.toString());
   **Error here** playlistRepository.saveAndFlush(fullRefinedPlaylist);
    log.info("Saved a playlist called {}", fullRefinedPlaylist.getName());
}
```

Comment: That likely is not the full stacktrace because the message "invalid stream header: 5C786163" is not included.

Comment: Apologies,shall edit now.

Comment: Also, 5C786163 decodes to \xac in ASCII. Typically this means something went wrong during the serialization process, and now when it tries to deserialize, oops

Comment: A right pain to debug, It worked correctly using h2 as a datasource but have moved to postgres during the last couple of weeks.

Comment: Has it ever worked since the move? I don't know if changing data sources might affect the way existing data is stored and therefore retrieved. Have you tried testing it on newly generated data?

Comment: It has never worked since the move, The service pulls fresh data from Spotify Api and it then uses a java wrapper which in turn is refined into those POJOs. The database is wiped on a reset.

Comment: I don't know which object it's trying to serialize because the stacktrace doesn't seem to indicate which line made the call to saveAndFlush, but try removing each field one by one from that object in your serializable class and then see when you can manage to serialize it. Maybe there's an issue with one of the types

Comment: Sorry the code is on this branch https://github.com/AlastairMiller/Spotify-Polling-Service/tree/Update-Spotify-Wrapper-to-version-2.0/src/main/java/com/sps/service              
RefreshLocalDBservice line 166 ` toplaylistRepository.saveAndFlush(fullRefinedPlaylist); `

Comment: Ok so it's serializing a RefinedPlaylist. Try taking out each field one by one and then see if you can serialize it. Might start by taking out the RefinedUser and RefinedTrack to narrow things down

Comment: Many thanks will try that.